# How to set a appropriate inital number when calcutating square root by Newton Method?

Tags: c, square-root

I have observed that the bigger a number is, the more loop count it needs to get a correct square root. If I fix the cycle times and initial number, when the calculated number grow bigger, the root become less accurate, but if I can make sure the initial is not far bigger than the square root, I suppose I can always get a accurate square root. So, how to make this initial number approximately same?

Comment: In any of the iterative solvers, Newton's, Adam's predictor/corrector, your ballpark value should not matter to terribly much as long as your solutions converge fairly aggressively. It has been a while, but there were several university level projects that looked at various algorithms for choosing initial input for iterative solutions. Without more specifics, I would suggest poking around for "choosing initial values" for numerical solutions square root". and see what comes back.

Comment: have a look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Answer (score 2):

The functions from the standard C library that help most are [`frexp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/frexp.html) and
[`ldexp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ldexp.html).

- `double frexp(double x, int *p)`

  Returns either 0 or a fraction, `f` in the range [0.5 .. 1.0).  Sets `*p` to the power of two such that the *`f * 2`<sup>`*p`</sup>* equals `x`.
- `double ldexp(double x, int p)`

  Returns *`x * 2`<sup>`p`</sup>*

Hence, a decent first approximation to the square root of `x` can be found by:

```
int p;
double f = frexp(x, &p);
double r = ldexp(f, p / 2);
```

As this code shows, you need at most 5 Newton-Raphson 'divide and average' cycles to produce a fully accurate answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

static double test_sqrt(double x)
{
    if (x <= 0.0)
        return 0.0;
    int p;
    double frac = frexp(x, &p);
    printf(" x = %22.15e;     f = %22.15e; p = %d\n", x, frac, p);
    double x0 = ldexp(frac, p / 2);
    printf("x0 = %22.15e; x0*x0 = %22.15e\n", x0, x0 * x0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        double x1 = (x / x0 + x0) / 2.0;
        printf("x1 = %22.15e; x1*x1 = %22.15e\n", x1, x1 * x1);
        x0 = x1;
    }
    printf(" r = %22.15e;   r*r = %22.15e;  x = %22.15e\n", x0, x0 * x0, x);
    return x0;
}

int main(void)
{
    double x = 1.23456E-125;
    while (x < 1E+125)
    {
        test_sqrt(x);
        x *= 987.654;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Extracts from the output:

```
 x = 1.234560000000000e-125;     f =  5.223124843710012e-01; p = -414
x0 =  2.539342632858085e-63; x0*x0 = 6.448261007050633e-126
x1 =  3.700536659343551e-63; x1*x1 = 1.369397156714553e-125
x1 =  3.518350710213579e-63; x1*x1 = 1.237879172006039e-125
x1 =  3.513633767135102e-63; x1*x1 = 1.234562224955201e-125
x1 =  3.513630600961067e-63; x1*x1 = 1.234560000001003e-125
x1 =  3.513630600959640e-63; x1*x1 = 1.234560000000000e-125
 r =  3.513630600959640e-63;   r*r = 1.234560000000000e-125;  x = 1.234560000000000e-125
 x = 1.219318122240000e-122;     f =  5.037734516005438e-01; p = -404
x0 =  7.837474714727561e-62; x0*x0 = 6.142600990399386e-123
x1 =  1.169750645469021e-61; x1*x1 = 1.368316572575191e-122
x1 =  1.106062520605688e-61; x1*x1 = 1.223374299488608e-122
x1 =  1.104228909406935e-61; x1*x1 = 1.219321484370028e-122
x1 =  1.104227387018778e-61; x1*x1 = 1.219318122242317e-122
x1 =  1.104227387017728e-61; x1*x1 = 1.219318122240000e-122
 r =  1.104227387017728e-61;   r*r = 1.219318122240000e-122;  x = 1.219318122240000e-122

 x =  8.193538364768438e-27;     f =  6.339443253229819e-01; p = -86
x0 =  7.207112563753321e-14; x0*x0 =  5.194247150661096e-27
x1 =  9.287898167957462e-14; x1*x1 =  8.626505237834758e-27
x1 =  9.054816977123554e-14; x1*x1 =  8.198971048920493e-27
x1 =  9.051817090894058e-14; x1*x1 =  8.193539264700178e-27
x1 =  9.051816593794011e-14; x1*x1 =  8.193538364768461e-27
x1 =  9.051816593793999e-14; x1*x1 =  8.193538364768438e-27
 r =  9.051816593793999e-14;   r*r =  8.193538364768438e-27;  x =  8.193538364768438e-27
 x =  8.092380940117008e-24;     f =  6.114430162915473e-01; p = -76
x0 =  2.224416735012882e-12; x0*x0 =  4.948029811005370e-24
x1 =  2.931197771052297e-12; x1*x1 =  8.591920373021955e-24
x1 =  2.845986967837607e-12; x1*x1 =  8.099641821101499e-24
x1 =  2.844711332870451e-12; x1*x1 =  8.092382567361578e-24
x1 =  2.844711046858202e-12; x1*x1 =  8.092380940117088e-24
x1 =  2.844711046858188e-12; x1*x1 =  8.092380940117008e-24
 r =  2.844711046858188e-12;   r*r =  8.092380940117008e-24;  x =  8.092380940117008e-24

 x =  7.511130028860641e-06;     f =  9.844988351428219e-01; p = -17
x0 =  3.845698574776648e-03; x0*x0 =  1.478939752803914e-05
x1 =  2.899411787388324e-03; x1*x1 =  8.406588712846356e-06
x1 =  2.744991037655443e-03; x1*x1 =  7.534975796808706e-06
x1 =  2.740647532044505e-03; x1*x1 =  7.511148894901633e-06
x1 =  2.740644090149702e-03; x1*x1 =  7.511130028872487e-06
x1 =  2.740644090147541e-03; x1*x1 =  7.511130028860642e-06
 r =  2.740644090147541e-03;   r*r =  7.511130028860642e-06;  x =  7.511130028860641e-06
 x =  7.418397617524327e-03;     f =  9.495548950431139e-01; p = -7
x0 =  1.186943618803892e-01; x0*x0 =  1.408835154219280e-02
x1 =  9.059718094019462e-02; x1*x1 =  8.207849194310363e-03
x1 =  8.624024859090236e-02; x1*x1 =  7.437380477020637e-03
x1 =  8.613019058546711e-02; x1*x1 =  7.418409730288888e-03
x1 =  8.613012026886571e-02; x1*x1 =  7.418397617529272e-03
x1 =  8.613012026883701e-02; x1*x1 =  7.418397617524329e-03
 r =  8.613012026883701e-02;   r*r =  7.418397617524329e-03;  x =  7.418397617524327e-03
 x =  7.326810080538372e+00;     f =  9.158512600672964e-01; p = 3
x0 =  1.831702520134593e+00; x0*x0 =  3.355134122267418e+00
x1 =  2.915851260067297e+00; x1*x1 =  8.502188570836042e+00
x1 =  2.714301457717203e+00; x1*x1 =  7.367432403365734e+00
x1 =  2.706818441652081e+00; x1*x1 =  7.326866076067802e+00
x1 =  2.706808098230342e+00; x1*x1 =  7.326810080645360e+00
x1 =  2.706808098210579e+00; x1*x1 =  7.326810080538371e+00
 r =  2.706808098210579e+00;   r*r =  7.326810080538371e+00;  x =  7.326810080538372e+00
 x =  7.236353283284045e+03;     f =  8.833439066508844e-01; p = 13
x0 =  5.653401002565660e+01; x0*x0 =  3.196094289581041e+03
x1 =  9.226700501282829e+01; x1*x1 =  8.513200214037281e+03
x1 =  8.534770092045144e+01; x1*x1 =  7.284230052406829e+03
x1 =  8.506722020095668e+01; x1*x1 =  7.236431952718052e+03
x1 =  8.506675780525467e+01; x1*x1 =  7.236353283497856e+03
x1 =  8.506675780399794e+01; x1*x1 =  7.236353283284046e+03
 r =  8.506675780399794e+01;   r*r =  7.236353283284046e+03;  x =  7.236353283284045e+03
 x =  7.147013265648620e+06;     f =  8.519903738079810e-01; p = 23
x0 =  1.744876285558745e+03; x0*x0 =  3.044593251905283e+06
x1 =  2.920438142779372e+03; x1*x1 =  8.528958945800630e+06
x1 =  2.683839109930689e+03; x1*x1 =  7.202992367993553e+06
x1 =  2.673410187023612e+03; x1*x1 =  7.147122028081623e+06
x1 =  2.673389845507460e+03; x1*x1 =  7.147013266062398e+06
x1 =  2.673389845430072e+03; x1*x1 =  7.147013265648622e+06
 r =  2.673389845430072e+03;   r*r =  7.147013265648622e+06;  x =  7.147013265648620e+06

 x =  5.714937347533526e+60;     f =  8.891035606430090e-01; p = 202
x0 =  2.254145324628333e+30; x0*x0 =  5.081171144543771e+60
x1 =  2.394723262542396e+30; x1*x1 =  5.734699504161695e+60
x1 =  2.390597074573772e+30; x1*x1 =  5.714954372960678e+60
x1 =  2.390593513658524e+30; x1*x1 =  5.714937347546205e+60
x1 =  2.390593513655872e+30; x1*x1 =  5.714937347533526e+60
x1 =  2.390593513655872e+30; x1*x1 =  5.714937347533526e+60
 r =  2.390593513655872e+30;   r*r =  5.714937347533526e+60;  x =  5.714937347533526e+60
 x =  5.644380731040877e+63;     f =  8.575455938313579e-01; p = 212
x0 =  6.957236395157723e+31; x0*x0 =  4.840313825810723e+63
x1 =  7.535100118309196e+31; x1*x1 =  5.677773379294325e+63
x1 =  7.512942052902534e+31; x1*x1 =  5.644429829027134e+63
x1 =  7.512909377296952e+31; x1*x1 =  5.644380731147647e+63
x1 =  7.512909377225895e+31; x1*x1 =  5.644380731040878e+63
x1 =  7.512909377225895e+31; x1*x1 =  5.644380731040878e+63
 r =  7.512909377225895e+31;   r*r =  5.644380731040878e+63;  x =  5.644380731040877e+63

 x = 4.457671009241398e+120;     f =  8.631370354723219e-01; p = 401
x0 =  1.387007739709396e+60; x0*x0 = 1.923790470013767e+120
x1 =  2.300441914113688e+60; x1*x1 = 5.292033000211049e+120
x1 =  2.119093716219477e+60; x1*x1 = 4.490558178120875e+120
x1 =  2.111333991241823e+60; x1*x1 = 4.457731222573127e+120
x1 =  2.111319731695020e+60; x1*x1 = 4.457671009444733e+120
x1 =  2.111319731646867e+60; x1*x1 = 4.457671009241398e+120
 r =  2.111319731646867e+60;   r*r = 4.457671009241398e+120;  x = 4.457671009241398e+120
 x = 4.402636602961303e+123;     f =  8.325007281566217e-01; p = 411
x0 =  4.280886694234198e+61; x0*x0 = 1.832599088887140e+123
x1 =  7.282645088745868e+61; x1*x1 = 5.303691948863432e+123
x1 =  6.664013166606369e+61; x1*x1 = 4.440907148470304e+123
x1 =  6.635298828449913e+61; x1*x1 = 4.402719054282879e+123
x1 =  6.635236697622269e+61; x1*x1 = 4.402636603347328e+123
x1 =  6.635236697331380e+61; x1*x1 = 4.402636602961305e+123
 r =  6.635236697331380e+61;   r*r = 4.402636602961305e+123;  x = 4.402636602961303e+123
```

You can apply more sophisticated techniques if you wish (for example, improving the estimate of the fraction), but the `frexp()` and `ldexp()` functions are likely to be useful.

You can find a discussion of this in Plauger's [The Standard C Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099), and also in Bentley's [More Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201118890).

Answer (score 1):

> So, how to make this initial number approximately same?

That's a catch-22 problem. If you can find out the a number that's approximately the same, why would you need to solve for it at all?

I don't think there is any good formula you can use for the first guess that works for all numbers.

You could use a initial value based on the range in which a number falls.

For example:

1. For all numbers less than `1.0`, use `2*x` as the initial value.
2. For all numbers between `1.0` and `1.0E4`, use `x/1.0E2` as the initial value.
3. For all numbers between `1.0E4` and `1.0E8`, use `x/1.0E6` as the initial value.

etc.